# Unable to connect sample bot framework project to luis API

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

**What I have done so far:**

1. Created a sample Microsoft Bot Framework project from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-quickstart)
2. Created s sample LIUS application, with a few intents, entities and utterances.
3. Have also tested the App in browser through the endpoint url, which seems to be working fine

**The Problem(s):**

I am having multiple problems, maybe they are trivial for an expert but i cant seem to get them resolved

1. "Endpoint Hits Per Period" section, in the luis dashboard, doesn't show any hit when I perform step 3 above. (But I am still sure my Sample Bot Framework app is hitting the url, I verified it through live wire-shark trace.) Why is it not updating?
2. Emulator is showing this error. From where is this error coming, the application is crashing somewhere?:

   "Exception: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
   [File of type 'text/plain']"
3. I am unable to have any insight into the project as to what response is coming from luis, where can I write a debug line to see the request and response?

Here is my code:

```
[LuisModel("b5439fa6-5be1-4680-bc46-379698e780ed", "045c3ef0bfc14040b7b35079ea030a98", domain: "westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com")]
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : LuisDialog<object>
{
    public RootDialog()
    {
    }
    public RootDialog(ILuisService service)
        : base(service)
    {
    }

    [LuisIntent("")]
    public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        <some code written here>
    }

    [LuisIntent("FAQs.Data.Coverage")]
    public async Task Coverage(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        <some code written here>
    }

    [LuisIntent("FAQs.Data.Info")]
    public async Task Info(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        <some code written here>
    }

    [LuisIntent("FAQs.Data.Package")]
    public async Task Package(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        <some code written here>
    }

    [LuisIntent("FAQs.Data.PhoneSupport")]
    public async Task PhoneSupport(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        <some code written here>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hit your endpoint directly and received the following message:

> `Model not published. Please publish your model before hitting the endpoint.`

To publish you'll visit your app's Publish App page where you can also select a key to use with the endpoint. You can find more information on publishing at this page of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/publishapp).

Before you've done this though, please go to your LUIS account's settings (click on your name in the top right corner next to *Sign Out*) and regenerate your Programmatic API Key. This way no one will be able to use the key you provided in your question.

Comment: thanks thats what i wanted to know how really did you hit the endpoint directly to get "Model not published" I was not able to figure out what is happening at the back end. Doesnt the endpoint get hit when you paste the url in the browser?

Comment: thanks a bunch Steven G, Problem#2 is solved, please guide about points 1 and 3 as well. The dashboard is still not showing the updated stats after I hit the endpoint url

Comment: For #2 I created your endpoint from the parameters used in your LuisModel instantiation, and then like you said, pasted that link into the browser. For #1 are you still using your Programmatic API Key or have you switched to an endpoint key?

Comment: For #3 have you tried using breakpoints to find your query and your LuisResult? Inside the code for your intents you can access the results from  `LuisResult result`

Answer (score 0):

You will get this problem when you have published your app in staging environment and have set the attribute staging=false in the URL